# Why my ImageView would not change width in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-imageview

I'm developing an Android app with avatar (the image icon), the ImageView is inside an RelativeLayout like this

```
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/indicators"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/conversation_avatar_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/conversation_list_left_indicator_height"
        android:layout_below="@id/contact_image"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/smaller_def_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/smaller_def_margin"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_reply"/>
```

However, I cannot change the width of this ImageView when I make the contact_image invisible because indicator takes less space. The code is like below

```
            indicators.getLayoutParams().width = width;
            indicatorsWidth = indicators.getWidth();
            indicators.requestLayout();
```

After `indicators.requestLayout();` the width of the indicator still keeps the old one not changed to width. I'm wondering why this can happen? I also tried `indicators.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);` but still doesn't work. 
I did find some interesting, even though `indicators.getWidth()` is still the old value, `indicators.getLayoutParams().width` is the new width now, and ImageView size doesn't change at all.
Update : I found what `view.getWidth()` is, and then I used `indicators.setLeft()` and `indicators.setRight()`, this time `indicators.getWidth()` is also the new width, however, the size still doesn't change, I checked it and found that `indicators.getMeasuredWidth()` is still the old value, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue may be `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` if the height of the `ImageView` is the constraining factor. The view will be resized to fit the height and maintain the aspect ratio by adjusting the width. See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#CENTER).

> Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least one axis (X or Y) will fit exactly. The result is centered inside dst.

Here is a small app to play with this concept. You will see that even though the width is change, the height is not with `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`. If you change it to `android:scaleType="fitXY"`, you will see a change. This may not be  your issue exactly, but you can use this code which is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to test out some ideas.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ImageView indicators = findViewById(R.id.indicators);
        indicators.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                indicators.getLayoutParams().width = 500;
                indicators.requestLayout();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/indicators"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought your explanation is good. But then I use `indicators.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_END);` and FIT_XY, still doesn't work. This is really strange.

Comment: I updated the question, seems layoutpramas.width get changed while imageview.width doesn't change....

Comment: I updated again, used `setLeft()` and `setRight()` to get the correct width, however the `getMeasuredWidth()` is still the old value. The size doesn't get changed.

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was actually because there is a class which is responsible for determining all the view's coordinates, however, it measured first, thus you can't change it on the fly. But what you said is correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When modifying `LayoutParams`, you have to reassign the object back to the view or there will be no effect.

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myView.getLayoutParams();
params.width = newWidth;
myView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

This last line is what actually changes the width of the view.

Comment: @litaoshen I'm not sure what you mean. The params are modified when you call `params.width = foo`, and then the new params actually take effect when you call `myView.setLayoutParams()`.

Comment: I tried the same thing but it doesn't work. I shouldn't say params, sorry. Actually params.mWidth get changed but view.getWidth() didn't get changed, then if I manually change mLeft and mRight, getWidth() will get changed too. But getMeasuredWidth() would still keep the old value. You can see my update.

Comment: @litaoshen if you post your entire layout as well as the full code you're attempting, I will be more able to help

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was actually because there is a class which is responsible for determining all the view's coordinates, however, it measured first, thus you can't change it on the fly. But what you said is correct. Thank you!